# css how to force a layer to be in the back (z-index doesn't work)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Normally, this is how it looks:

[image: OK]

But if I resize the page with the Internet Browser (Firefox), sometimes the next no wanted thing happens:

[image: Unwanted]

This is because I set a negative margin to the carousel as I want to put it right next to the navigation menu:

```
.carousel {
    margin-top:-45px;
}
```

I tried to solve it with z-index. I set the next property to the navigation menu:

```
.top-layer{
    z-index:9999;
}
```

And the next to the Twitter Bootstrap Carousel:

```
.back-layer{
    z-index:0;  
}
```

I also tried with `overflow:scroll;`. This is how it looks:

[image: overflow:scroll]

Why the Internet Browser (Firefox) put the carousel on the top? How could we force to draw it in the bottom?

Comment: I think you must position the elements to be able to use `z-index`, try setting `position:relative;` or similar on the elements.

Comment: As @KristerAndersson has mentioned, elements MUST have either `position:relative;` or `position:absolute` in order for `z-index` to affect them.

Comment: I added `position:relative;` to `.top-layer` and `.back-layer`. It is in the back now! :)

Comment: @KristerAndersson answer my question (or I'll do it if you prefer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the `z-index` property to have any effect it must be used on elements that are positioned as `absolute`, `relative` or `fixed`.

Read more: [Understanding CSS z-index - The stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/Understanding_z-index/The_stacking_context)

Answer (score 0):

To use `z-index` you must have `position` set to `absolute`, `relative`, or `fixed` according to the [W3C wiki](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/z-index).